# Where do I modify the nameservers for my domain when no service "takes responsibility"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, dreamhost, nameservers, amazon-route53

I think I may have made a mistake when migrating my DreamHost registered domain to Amazon's Route 53 service. I didn't modify the DNS settings on DreamHost's end during the migration. So now, my DreamHost DNS panel says the following:

Change example.com's whois nameservers
To modify your domain's whois information, please visit the registrar you registered example.com with (looks like it's not us!)

Even though the domain is originally registered with them. Now Route 53 has (apparently) completely taken over the domain, and I have the following delegation set:

ns-567.awsdns-06.net
ns-1362.awsdns-42.org
ns-387.awsdns-48.com
ns-1717.awsdns-22.co.uk

But, I also get the following message:

Before the Domain Name System will start to route queries for this domain to Route 53 name servers, you must update the name server records either with the current DNS service or with the registrar for the domain, as applicable.

Amazon does their domain stuff through Gandi, but I am not given a handle to log in to their service. So who is this "registrar" the message tells me about? Is it Amazon or Dreamhost?

At the moment, if I whois example.com I get the following nameservers:

ns1.dreamhost.com
ns2.dreamhost.com
ns3.dreamhost.com

What to do?

Comment: This question is for server fault

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you properly told dreamhost (who is the registrar for your domain), that route53/aws will handle DNS traffic for you - that is 1/2 of what you need to do.

The other half is you need to setup your domain in route53(aws), not Gandi. Basically you told dreamhost that r53 will handle it, but you haven't yet told r53 how to handle it.

This document may help:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html